# How to load text containing commas in a single Excel cell with EPPlus

Tags: .net, epplus

I'm giving a try to the [EPPlus library](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) and I'm stucked at this: I have to load a text in a single cell, but when this text contains a comma the code that I'm using split my text along multiple cells (along the right direction).
Here is the code that I'm using to load the text:

```
using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
{
   //Create the worksheet
   ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("MySheet");
   using (ExcelRange range = ws.Cells[1, 1])
   {
      range.LoadFromText("this works");
   }
   using (ExcelRange range = ws.Cells[1, 2])
   {
      range.LoadFromText("this, splits my , text in 3 parts");
   }
}
```

I don't find a way to operate on a single cell or to instruct the LoadFromText method to not split my text.

Comment: Can you wrap the text in double quote (")?

Comment: I have not set any delimiter; my text comes from the database and should load into a single cell; I think Excel is using comma as delimiter by default

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could wrap it in double quotes by specifying the `TextQualifier`

```
using (ExcelRange range = ws.Cells[1, 1])
{
   var format = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelTextFormat();
   format.Delimiter = ',';
   format.TextQualifier = '"';
   format.DataTypes = new[] { eDataTypes.String };
   range.LoadFromText("this, should, work, also, now", format);
}
```

Comment: thank you Tim, but it's not working. I have tried to pass the format variable to the LoadFromText method, but in this case I get an exception (index out of bound). The only method for now that works is to change the delimiter, but in this case the new delimiter could also be contained in the text ...

Comment: with a different delimiter (I used a character not present in my text) it's working

Answer (score 1):

You can actually reference a single cell and set its value and avoid to modify the Delimiter.

```
using (ExcelRange range = ws.Cells[1, 1])
{
    range.First().Value = "this, should, work";
}
```

The above assumes that the referenced cell is already created. If it has not already been set to a value, it will give an *Object reference not set to an instance of an object* error. So, to avoid this you can set a dummy value right before, just to create the cell.

```
using (ExcelRange range = ws.Cells[1, 1])
{
    range.LoadFromText("-"); // This will create the cell
    range.First().Value = "this, should, work";
}
```