# VB How can I use commas within an excel cell?

Tags: excel, vb.net, epplus

I want to use commas within an excel cell whilst keeping commas as the delimiter.

Sub

```
    Dim countStations As Integer
    Dim stationI
    Dim rawFileArray() As String = File.ReadAllLines(rawFileName)
    For Each station In stationsNameList
        stationI = stationList(countStations)
        For i As Integer = 0 To rawFileArray.Count - 1
            If rawFileArray(i).IndexOf(station, 0) <> -1 Then
                stationI.rawData += rawFileArray(i) & "," & stationI.stationName & "," & stationI.region & vbNewLine
            End If
        Next
        CreateStationsXLSX(station, countStations)
        countStations += 1
    Next
```

End Sub

Sub (ByRef station As String, ByRef countStations As Integer)

```
    Dim fi = New FileInfo("FQR Generator Data\Stations\" & station & ".xlsx")
    Using p As New ExcelPackage(fi)
        Dim wsQuantity = p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Quantity Summary")
        Dim wsQuality = p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Quality Summary")
        Dim wsRaw = p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Raw")
        Dim wsStation = p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(station)
        Dim currentCell As Integer = 0
        Dim stationToLoad As String = stationList(countStations).rawData


        'Importing Raw Data into worksheet
        wsRaw.Cells("A1").LoadFromText(stationsHeader)
        wsRaw.Cells("A2").LoadFromText(stationToLoad)

        p.Save()
    End Using
    'GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "FQR Generator Data\Stations\", station
```

End Sub

Here is what is entered into excel ...
[Actual Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFYry.png)

Here is what is i want entered into excel...
[Wanted Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWcjV.png)

Comment: I think you need to research the [Strings.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.join?view=netcore-3.1) method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load text containing commas in a single Excel cell with EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356959/how-to-load-text-containing-commas-in-a-single-excel-cell-with-epplus) . The code is C# but it's easy to [convert between C# and VB.NET](https://converter.telerik.com/)

Comment: @JvdV I believe this will still use "," as a delimiter even if it is within a Substring

Comment: @dkettle01 did you check the link I posted? I think it should explain to you what to do.

Comment: @ADyson I have, I need to rejig my code to fit so i'm in the middle of seeing whether it will work ... I will keep you updated :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use LoadFromText, use Value:

```
wsRaw.Cells("A2").Value = "this,with,commas"
```

Comment: This copies the whole string into a single cell. It should still use commas as a delimiter, but i need a way of explicitly stating when not to use commas as a delimiter .

Comment: I didn't get you. Vary your use between Value and LoadFromText depending on whether you want commas to be or not to be a delimiter?

Comment: If you check this out in [the fine manual](https://riptutorial.com/epplus/example/26605/import-data-from-csv-file) you can see that LoadFromFile has an overload that takes two parameters, the second being a *format* object that allows you to specify a delimiter that is not a comma.. if that's what you're asking

Comment: I have used ' Dim rawFileArray() As String = File.ReadAllLines(rawFileName)' to collect the data from an excel file ... Is there a way I can change the delimiter on when collecting the data as well? If so I can definitely use your recommendation

Comment: i didn't really understand your question. What is "collecting the data" ?

Comment: From an Excel file I am converting each row into a string value ... The delimiter is defaulted to a comma, is there a way to change the default delimiter ?